# Is it possible / how to get number of a particular Facebook Group members (even if number of them is 500+)?

Tags: facebook

I need to monitor number of the facebook group users and display it on the website. I know that it is possible to get User IDs using their API, but they are limited to 500 only (if the total number of members is 500+).

What would be the easiest way to get total number of members that signed up to a Facebook Group that I'd set up? Is this at all possible?

Comment: Madarco, could you be more explicit by posting the whole code, please?

Answer (score 3):

If you write an http bot, it shouldn't be very hard to scrap, given that real-time performance is not the key.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a FQL query like this:

```
SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = <group_id> limit 500
SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = <group_id> limit 500 offset 500
SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = <group_id> limit 500 offset 1000
...
```

---

#### Get the number of members

Do it inside a loop (until you get 0 results) and you'll get the total number of group members

```
    perPage = 500
    for count in range(100):
        res = fql('SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = %s limit %d offset %d' % (fbUserId, perPage, perPage * count))
        if len(res) == 0:
            break
        friends += len(res)
```

---

#### Get the members detail

You can even join with the user FQL table to have all the user detail:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN ( 
         SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = <group_id> limit 500 offset %d )
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for `Groups.getMembers` it isn't possible to get > 500 group members with an API call. Worse, you seem to only be able to get 500 *random* members.

You may want to consider using Facebook Connect with your site instead. I'm no expert on Connect but I believe you wont have this problem using it since you are actually writing Facebook-specific code -- seems like there would be no purpose in limiting results. That'd be the direction I'd look, at least.

Good luck.