# Facebook API: get public info of the group

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-group

I am building a simple app with NodeJS and I need to list several Facebook groups and sort them by the number of members.
My App does not need any sensitive/personal information, just some public info (group's name, description, members, etc).
To use Group endpoint my app needs to be reviewed and approved. It asks for things like Privacy Policy URL and items that the app would use from the API.
Also, from what I have read here
[Facebook API: How to get count of group members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598572/facebook-api-how-to-get-count-of-group-members) it seems that "After 90 days from releasing Graph API v2.12 all the above requests will require an access token of an Admin of the Group".
Is there a way to get the public info of the group without all this bureaucracy?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around those requirements. I strongly recommend you follow Facebook's recommended steps for accessing data. Attempting to work around Facebook's approval and permission system is more trouble than it's worth, as your app is liable to have it's access revoked at any time, or break with new API updates.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question correctly. I want to find a way to retrieve the number of members in the group from Facebook API without being an admin of this group.

Comment: Right. You can't do it. Your app needs the authentication token of a group admin.